# Android Design Support Library: RecyclerView animating up in a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I'm using the latest version of the design support library and have ran into a problem. Within a coordinator layout, containing a CollpasingToolbarLayout and RecyclerView, the RecyclerView will sometimes animate upwards the height of the status bar. I'm sure this has to do with the fact that this view hides the statusbar using the "fitsSystemWindows" xml attribute.

Here is a screen of what happens exactly:

[image: error]

As you can see there is a margin at the bottom of the RecyclerView which shouldn't be there.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@color/activity_background_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_image"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fa_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        bit:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Where "toolbar_image" is this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/actionbar_body_color"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_left_margin"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Bandsintown.ToolbarTitleTextAppearance"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/toolbar_title_bottom_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_gradient_ascending"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_top_gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_gradient_descending"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/toolbar_title_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Widget.Bandsintown.ToolbarSubtitleTextAppearance"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I also recorded a video of what is happening. In this clip it takes a few tries to get it to happen, so you can see what it SHOULD be doing first, and then see the bug after.

Here is the link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97787025/device-2015-07-24-143017.mp4

The same problem doesn't happen in a CoordinatorLayout I use elsewhere that works with a NestedScrollView. Any help on this would be appreciated, I get the feeling its a library bug but if there is a fix, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar problem recently.  I don't have an idea about how to solve it, but maybe sharing my problem in detail can help others better solve yours:

1. Have you tried switching support library to an older version? Only when using support library 24.0.0 or higher, do I get your bug.
2. Are you using nested recyclerviews? After a few tests, I found that my bug comes only when I stop scrolling, or the fragment containing my out recyclerview is displayed(though you're not using fragments here) and a nested recyclerview is partly displayed.  Then the outer recyclerview automatically scrolls until the top or bottom of the nested recyclerview on screen.